# ¿Como devuelvo una URL obtenida de un Fragment a un Menú?

Tags: java, android

El problema que tengo es que necesito pasar la **URL** de una imagen que guarda en **FIREBASE** desde un `Fragment` a un `String` que pasa la dirección a la librería **Glide** para mostrar la imagen de perfil en un `ImageView` del menú pero no esta funcionando, que puede ser?.

**Boton que sube la imagen y devuelve la URL:**

```
btn_SubirImagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pDialog.show();
            ImagenPerfil.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ImagenPerfil.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagenPerfil.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

            String id_firebase = email;
            id_firebase = id_firebase.substring(0, id_firebase.length() - 4);

            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference(id_firebase);
            StorageReference foto = storageRef.child("foto_perfil");
            uploadTask = foto.putBytes(data);

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Uri u = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    savePreferences("imagen_perfil",u.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Imagen subida con exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_MenuLateral.class);
                    i.putExtra("URL_IMAGEN",u.toString());
                    startActivityForResult(i, getActivity().RESULT_OK);
                    getActivity().finish();

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al subir la imágen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress;
                    progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    int i = (int) progress;
                    pDialog.setProgress(i);

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**OnActivityResult que recibe la URL y llama a un metodo para que actualice la imagen:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL: "+data.getStringExtra("URL_IMAGEN"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        urlProfileImg = data.getStringExtra("URL_IMAGEN");
        loadNavHeader(name,email);
    }
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Este es el metodo que se encarga de cargar las imágenes con **Glide:**

```
private void loadNavHeader(String name, String email) {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtWebsite.setText(email);

    // loading header background image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

    // Loading profile image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new Circulo(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    //Sirve para mostrar el punto de color
    //navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}
```

Comment: La Url la estas obteniendo de manera correcta?, es decir, esta llegando al onActivityResult?, si es el caso, muestra el código de como cargas la imagen con Glide. Si lo que quieres es actualizar una por la que ya estaba, es decir, si tienes una misma Url aunque la imagen cambie, debes utilizar una firma.

Comment: Si ya tengo una URL pero esa la cargo de Facebook, y la que quiero pasar es de Firebase.

Comment: Pero una pregunta, la URL es la misma siempre?, lo que cambia es la imagen desde el Storage? lo que buscas es actualizar la imagen utilizando la misma URL? Se esta llamando onActivityResult?

Comment: No, la URL es diferente.

Comment: El problema es que no esta llegando el Url a onActivityResult?, porque si la Url llega diferente, deberia cargar la imagen sin problemas. El imageview mantiene la imagen anterior o cual es el problema?. Si es que no esta devolviendo el resultado desde el Fragment a onActivityResult, puedes decir donde esta ese onActivityResult, en un Fragment o en un Activity?

Comment: Exacto, no esta llegando a onActivityResult, y esta en un Activity, osea en el menu principal, y la URL la mando desde un Fragment.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77367/discussion-between-andrespengineer-and-rosyec-parrado).

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo, decidí cambiar el `fragment` a un `activity` y resulta que estaba haciendo mal el uso del método, desde el menú debía iniciar la segunda actividad con `startActivityForResult`, luego de estar en la segunda actividad debía usar el método `setResult` con la **URL** que necesitaba pasar, luego finalizo la actividad y nuevamente en el menú, con el método `onActivityResult` recibo correctamente la **URL**.

**Acitivity Menu - Inicio Activity Perfil:**

```
btn_Perfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_MenuLateral.this, Activity_Perfil.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, request_code);
        }
    });
```

**Activity Perfil - Paso la URL:**

```
Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.putExtra("URL_IMAGEN",u.toString());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
```

**Activity Menu - Recibo la URL:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == request_code) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL: "+data.getStringExtra("URL_IMAGEN"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        urlProfileImg = data.getStringExtra("URL_IMAGEN");
        loadNavHeader(name,email);
    }
}
```